# Edit default input and response chatbot based on react + botframework-webchat?

Tags: reactjs, redux, botframework

I'm tried demo source code from [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started/e.host-with-react/) it's working fine.
[image]
**Things to try out**

```
help, markdown, card weather, layout carousel
```

I need to update new input like above.

Comment: What demo sourcecode did you use and what do you mean by 'default input and  response' and what did you already try?

Comment: @Hessel https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started/e.host-with-react/ i tried this page react sample it's also working fine. Please visit this page section **Things to try out** help, markdown, card weather, layout carousel. my expectations should be update the default input and the response. Ex: **my new input** with response from botframework-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Bot Framework Web Chat component** is a web-based chat-client for chatbots developed with the Bot Framework V4 SDK. It **is an **interface**** like Facebook messenger and helps to exchanges messages (spoken or text) with the chatbot. It does not contains the actual bot-logic.

**If you would like to change the default text send to, and the default response received from the chatbot, you need to change the bot-logic.**

You could start with modifying one of the chatbot samples provided by the team. The SDK supports multiple languages. There should be one of your liking.

I know there should be code in an answer but in this case I don't know what to show. My suggestion to you would be to start with documentation from the Bot Framework SDK team.

Quickstart Javascript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0